# No event is firing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In my website No button event is firing.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Add_Record" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" 
                  onclick="Button1_Click"  />
```

when I write code in the event handler. It does not call.
On every page of website I am facing this issue.

```
  <div id="eList">
        <p>Enter Your Email To Sign Up<br>
              For Our E-Newsletter:</p>
              <asp:TextBox ID="elist_input" runat="server" Width="169px">
              </asp:TextBox>
                  <br>
  <asp:Button class="elist_submit" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="56px"
      onclick="Unnamed1_Click" />

 <div id="display_menu_2">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Add_Record" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="true" onclick="Button1_Click"  />
```

**Page Directive**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="HomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="homePage" %>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?  Does your asp:Button have an OnClick property set?

Comment: Kindly check the code.

Comment: Can you run any code behind or is it just events that don't work? If so, check your .aspx is correctly referencing the code behind.

Comment: i am redirecting on event call. but it's not working

Comment: Post your page directive - At the top '<%@Page' line.  Also, post the C# or VB associated with these events.  Also, technically the property should be 'OnClick', same casing.

Comment: Page Directive.. <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="HomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="homePage" %>

Comment: Does a postback happen? If so, check Request.Forms("__EventTarget") and Request.Forms("__EventArgument") on Page Load to see what is happening. If no postback, make sure your form is included and is runat="server".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project must have been Web application project and the `CodeFile` attribute is valid only in Web site project for compiled pages, change it to the `CodeBehind` like this.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="homePage" %>
```

Comment: when I change the codeFile attribute with codebehind. Now I am finding these errors.. could not load MasterPage, could not load viewcarts etc

Comment: What is the type of your project 'Web application' or 'Web site'?

Comment: I am develping a e-commerce web application of buying products.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to call the event handlers. the problem was due to the header.ascx file. In that file I used form and also a form in Master page. As Master page is inhereted to all pages and header is also. due to two form in one page event handlers were not working..